# Record sounds using AudioQueue and AQRecorder from SpeakHere example

Tags: ios, recording, audioqueue

I can have 2 AQRecorder running at the same time?
I want to hold a recording into two files and I want to run two AudioQueueRef simultaneously, it is possible?

Thanks